# How to stage all modified and new files with vim-fugitive

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-fugitive

I know that you can use `GWrite` to stage current file. You can also use `GStatus` and `-` to stage the file you are selecting.

Is there a way to `GWrite` all the files or do `git add .` without using `GStatus` ?

Comment: In case you do want to use `:Gstatus` you can use the `-` command on a heading to (un-)stage all the files under that heading. Use fold motions, `zj` and `zk`, to jump between headings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `:h :Git`, which can

> Run an arbitrary git command. Similar to :!git [args]
>   but chdir to the repository tree first.

```
:Git add .
```

Answer (score 6):

Not the answer to your specific question but something I've learned from one of the screencasts specified in github/tpope/vim-fugitive/README.markdown is you can do a visual select all file lines, `-` to stage them all, then `cc` to commit, all from within the `Gstatus` screen.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just add a number before `-`. E.g. `5-` to stage/unstage 5 of them.

Answer (score 2):

Now I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
augroup custom_fugitive_mappings
    " delete custom_fugitive_mappings to avoid double runs
    au!
    " map 'A' to stage all in git status window
    au User FugitiveIndex nnoremap <buffer> A :Git add .<cr>
augroup END
```